# how to test Android application in LoadRunner?

Tags: android, performance-testing, loadrunner

I am using Load Runner for Calculating Response time on Web pages. Now, i am planning to test Android applications through Load Runner. I tried **TruClient** but i cant connect to ip. what to test Android Application on Load Runner?

Answer (score 0):

You capture the requests via proxy and then you play them back as you would with any other web virtual user

Be sure to include network emulation profiles in your test design because your bottleneck on performance will be how your application makes use of the congested 2g/3g/4g space at rush hour from the car and less so from wifi from the house or starbucks.

Answer (score 0):

The approach to handle android applications is 2 fold :

> Native/Hybrid Android Application

**Approach 1**

1. Connect the mobile device to the same network in which LoadRunner is installed (connect the device and Laptop to the same WiFi network.. in case of Desktop, connect the device via WiFi to the network on which the Desktop resides)
2. Make modifications on the WiFi settings of the device.

   Settings --> WiFi under Wireless Networks --> Press and hold the WiFi to which you have connected --> Select Modify Network --> Key in the Proxy server name (IP address of the machine on which the LoadRunner is installed) and Proxy port (the port on which LoadRunner listens)
3. Create a new project in LoadRunner in Mobile HTTP/HTML protocol (below LR 12.53) or in Web HTTP/HTML protocol (LR 12.53).
4. Upon clicking record button:

   **a) For below LR 12.53**:
   Select "Proxy Recording" option in the pop-up that you see.

[image]

Provide the port number that was specified in the previous step while configuring the port number on the device.

[image]

Once these configurations are made, the application needs to be traversed and the corresponding requests would be captured by LoadRunner.

**b) LoadRunner 12.53**: The options provided above are similar, however, they are available under Web HTTP/HTML protocol.

**Approach 2**

Use TruClient Native Mobile protocol. However, this requires the existence of HP Mobile Center for successful recording and replay of the scripts. Additionally, the load would be dependant on the number of real devices available/connected to the HP MC.

> Browser based Android Application

**Approach 1**

The mobile configuration mentioned above remains the same. This time, the traversing happens via the mobile browser.

**Approach 2**

If there is a mobile site available, like facebook has a m.facebook.com, the same could be recorded on normal Web HTTP/HTML protocol.

Hope this helps!